# ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Tags: filezilla

I'm trying to run filezilla in Windows Vista...
I turned off my firewall..
still I didn't able to connect...
help me to proceed....

Status: Resolving address of ftp.abc.net
Status: Connecting to 209.31.182.213:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".

Comment: This question seems old, abandoned, and rather low quality, so maybe it should be closed?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't proceed as the server you are trying to connect to (209.31.182.213) does not have the FTP server running.

You may need to contact the owners of that server and tell them the FTP server is not running.
Failing that, are you certain you are connecting to the correct server to begin with?